# Accessing remote mysql database via asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql

How would I go about connecting asp.net intranet pages with a remote mysql database?  I have full access to both servers.

Usually, I connect my asp.net intranet pages, with a sql server which is in our own internal company network, I've never needed to connect to a remove mysql server before.  However, I create php pages on our remote server all the time, which connect with a mysql server in the same network on which the php pages run.

**UPDATE 1:**

Forgot to mention that the asp.net pages are behind a firewall which only has ports http and ssh open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect using ADO.NET and the MySQL Connector available here:

http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

There are also other alternatives here:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/index.html

EDIT: The firewall shouldn't be an issue as you're establishing an outbound connection (from the website to your database).